# Anyone good at nested loops?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, nested

First post here FYI!
I got this graph that looks like this:

Graphs = {'g1': **[** **[** ['a1', 0], ['a2', 0] **]**, **[** ['e1', 0] **]**, {'a1': ['e1'], 'a2': ['e1'] } **]** }

What the graph is representing is abstract data structure of a graph with nodes and edges basically. It can represent one or several graphs.

I'm trying to "reach" "a1" so I can write it into a file like this example below:

a1,0;a2,0;a3,0

e1,0;e2,0

a1,e1,e2;a2,e1;a3,2

The intergers is another thing but it basically has two states 1 or 0 depending if you have crossed or not crossed a node or an edge.

In order to write this to the file I need a nested loop that reaches each node (vertex) and edge in the graph.

I have yet not found any good tutorials about nested loops with items in lists. Everyone just talk about `for i in range(3):` etc.

This is my code so far:

```
def Find_vertex(graphs):

for key in graphs:
    print(str(graphs[key][0][0][0]))
```

This prints out a1 but... yeah if I want everyone I should use a nested for-loop right?

I don't really know how this works. A link of this explained would be appreciated a lot since I don't seem to grip this.

Comment: How is the `Graphs` data structured? What is a node, what is an edge, why is there another dictionary in the structure?

Comment: ["a1", 0] is representing one node. and ["e1", 0] is representing one edge. The additional dictionary represent the mappings between the nodes and the edges.

Any further questions?

Comment: What does 'reaching `a1` mean? Are you trying to traverse the graph? What do the integers mean in the nodes and edges lists? Do they have bearing on how to traverse the graph?

Comment: What the graph is representing is abstract data structure of a graph with nodes and edges basically. I'm trying to "reach" "a1" so I can write it into a file like this example below:

a1,0;a2,0;a3,0
e1,0;e2,0
a1,e1,e2;a2,e1;a3,2

I'm not familiar with the term tranverse. 
The intergers is another thing but it basically has two states 1 or 0 depending if you have crossed or not crossed a node or an edge.

Comment: Why not explain this *in your question*? You can [edit] it to clarify it.

Comment: Better explained now perhaps? Sry for bad post, first timer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, took some time.

def save_graph(graphs):
    string = ""

```
tname = input("Skriv in namnet på filens namn: ")

thand = open(tname, 'w')

for key in graphs:
    for objekt in graphs[key][0]:
        string += str(objekt[0]) + ","
        string += str(objekt[1]) + ","
    string += ";"
    string += "\n"
#print(string)

for key in graphs:
    for objekt in graphs[key][1]:
        string += str(objekt[0]) + ","
        string += str(objekt[1]) + ","
    string += ";"
    string += "\n"
for graf in graphs:
    for key, value in graphs[graf][2].items():
        string += (key) + "," + (value[0]) +  ";"

string = string.replace(",;", "")
string = string[:-1]
print(string)

thand.write(str(string))
thand.close()
```